# How do I make authorized requests via Blazor to WebAPI while authenticating via Azure B2C?

Tags: c#, authorization, access-token, blazor, webapi

I'm trying to set up a new Blazor project - Client Side I think.  I also set up a Web API that the Blazor app can connect to in order to retrieve or post data.  The Blazor app can authenticate via Azure B2C and display that the user is logged in...however, the kicker is I can't setup the Blazor app to GET or POST successful authenticated requests against the API...it always returns back unauthorized.

Technically I'm thinking the Blazor app authenticates, but needs to acquire an access token which then needs to be attached to the requests to the Web API for [Authorized]...but how to implement that in C# with Blazor...that I have no idea.

I've seen documentation referencing JWT Bearer Tokens...is that something I should pursue?

I'm using the latest version of Blazor (currently 3.something-preview)...I set both the Blazor project and the Web API up using the Visual Studio templates selecting Authentication and used the same settings for Azure B2C.

Here's the code that I have working for calling the API:

```
@code {
    private WeatherForecast[] forecasts;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var responseJson = await Http.GetStringAsync("https://my-webapi.azurewebsites.net/WeatherForecast/");
        forecasts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherForecast[]>(responseJson);
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure I need to change the above to HttpMessage so that I can include the token in the header...

Not much to the WebApi controller, but here it is.

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
  using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
  using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

  namespace Journal.WebApi.Controllers
  {
      [Authorize]
      [ApiController]
      [Route("[controller]")]
      public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
      {
          private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
          {
              "Freezing", "Windy" 
              //"Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Cold","Mild", "Sprinkling","Raining", "Misty", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
          };

          private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

          public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
          {
              _logger = logger;
          }

          [HttpGet]
          public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
          {
              var rng = new Random();
              return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
              {
                  Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                  TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                  Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
              })
              .ToArray();
          }
      }
  }
```

Here's my Blazor startup file in case that helps...

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
    using Journal.Blazor.Data;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
    using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
    using System.Text;

    namespace Journal.Blazor
    {
        public class Startup
        {
            public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
            {
                Configuration = configuration;
            }

            public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

            // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
            // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
            public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddAzureADB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));

                services.AddRazorPages();
                services.AddServerSideBlazor();

                //ToDo:  only do this when in dev
                services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddCircuitOptions(options => { options.DetailedErrors = true; });

                // Server Side Blazor doesn't register HttpClient by default
                if (!services.Any(x => x.ServiceType == typeof(HttpClient)))
                {
                    // Setup HttpClient for server side in a client side compatible fashion
                    services.AddScoped<HttpClient>(s =>
                    {
                        // Creating the URI helper needs to wait until the JS Runtime is initialized, so defer it.      
                        var uriHelper = s.GetRequiredService<NavigationManager>();
                        return new HttpClient
                        {
                            BaseAddress = new Uri(uriHelper.BaseUri)
                        };
                    });
                }
            }

            // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
            {
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                }
                else
                {
                    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                    app.UseHsts();
                }

                app.UseHttpsRedirection();
                app.UseStaticFiles();

                app.UseRouting();

                app.UseAuthentication();
                app.UseAuthorization();

                app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapControllers();
                    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: That should help : [Quickstart: Set up sign-in for a single-page app using Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-quickstarts-spa).

Comment: @aguafrommars - That quickstart shows how to acquire the token using JavaScript, but not how to do this via C# in Blazor.  Do I need to fall back to JS in this case?

Comment: If you want to use MSAL.js then yes. You can also try with the desktop authentication using `Microsoft.Identity.Client` but take of one thing : you cannot safely store a client secret on SPA. It can work with the `PublicClientApplication` class